# Having stack overflow error when run the flutter project, how to know which part is the main cause?

Tags: flutter

I having some problem with my flutter project which i got the error `Stack overflow`.
Trying to build for the application that using stream to get the data from the https://www.themoviedb.org.

Getting no Problems under the visual studio problems tab, also able to run the project.

Here is my main.dart.

```dart
import 'package:app_01112020/bloc.dart';
import 'package:app_01112020/models/movie_model.dart';
import 'package:app_01112020/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MovieProvider(
      movieBloc: MovieBloc(API()),
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: "Movie App", theme: ThemeData(), home: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final movieBloc = MovieProvider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bloc Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: movieBloc.query.add,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Search for a Movie'),
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: movieBloc.log,
            builder: (context, snapshot) => Container(
              child: Text(snapshot?.data ?? ''),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: movieBloc.results,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              child: Image.network(
                                  "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" +
                                      snapshot.data[index].posterPath),
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].overview),
                          ));
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bloc.dart file

```dart
import 'package:app_01112020/models/movie_model.dart';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class MovieBloc {
  final API api;

  Stream<List<Movie>> _results = Stream.empty();
  Stream<String> _log = Stream.empty();

  ReplaySubject<String> _query = ReplaySubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get log => log;
  Stream<List<Movie>> get results => results;
  Sink<String> get query => _query;

  MovieBloc(this.api) {
    _results = _query.distinct().asyncMap(api.get).asBroadcastStream();
  }

  // Need to dispose else will have performance problem
  void dispose() {
    _query.close();
  }
}
```

Here is error log:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
MyHomePage
lib\main.dart:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      MovieBloc.log
package:app_01112020/bloc.dart:13
#1      MovieBloc.log
package:app_01112020/bloc.dart:13
#2      MovieBloc.log
package:app_01112020/bloc.dart:13
#3      MovieBloc.log
package:app_01112020/bloc.dart:13
#4      MovieBloc.log
package:app_01112020/bloc.dart:13
...
```

Please show me a way that I can have a deeper idea how should I debug for this kind of thing happen?
Feeling helpless when running the flutter and get this unclear error message.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it output any other information about the error or what is probable cause of the error?

Comment: `Stream<String> get log => log;`

This should be `Stream<String> get log => _log;`

Comment: same for results. `Stream<List<Movie>> get results => results;` should be `Stream<List<Movie>> get results => _results;`

Comment: Thanks for that remind.... @user6327816, now i got that works. btw, anything that i can do to enhance and stop this thing happen again>?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe dart linter might help

Comment: Ok, will try that. Do you know when using the `rxdart`, the older version have the 
```
   _log = Observable(results)
      .withLatestFrom(_query.stream, (_, query) => 'Result for $query')
      .asBroadcastStream();

```
In the latest version, already become deprecated, tried with the Stream also not help. 
So i remove this part of code, and let the app running.